# What persistence layer / database do the main GAME engines use?

Tags: game-engine

I have a keen interest in "embedded databases" like Berkeley DB, SQLite, eXtremeDB etc and am very curious as to what "databases" the major Game engines (or games in general) use to persist their data?

I would assume some of them use thier own "in house" persistence layers / databases.
Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a question IMHO. No body knows what DB's game studios uses (unless there are people who works in the industry and are not under NDA). I'm going to assume they use whatever suits they needs and that it depends on the game as well. Also don't add random not needed tags to your question, like C or LUA.

Comment: "major games" is way too vague to give an answer. To give 3 examples, browser games are quite "major" these days, first person shooters are quite "major", MMOGs are quite "major". They all have very different needs in terms of performance, scalability, transaction safety, integrity, and obfuscation. Thus, they would use very different data stores. As it is, a valid answer to the question would be "yes, all".

Comment: Sorry about adding it to Lua and C...;-) Won't do it again /...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most major game engines don't use any embedded database. They use config files or skripts with data instead.
IMHO embedded DBM for typical game engine is overkill.

Of course MMO-Engines use DB, but not embedded.